# Resident advisor: an advisor who resides or someone who advises residents?

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases, agent-nouns

[Google](//www.google.com/search?q=ra+dorm+site%3A.edu) assures me that there's a position at various postsecondary institutions called "resident assistant", "resident advisor", or "resident adviser". This is a student who lives in a dormitory and assists/advises its other residents.

When this phrase (whichever saw earliest use) was starting to be used, was it intended as

- resident<sub>​adjective</sub> advisor

(i.e. a local advisor, an advisor who resides in the dorm) or as

- resident<sub>​noun</sub> advisor

(i.e. someone who advises residents, à la "stamp collector")? Any evidence would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Columbia University Annual Report](http://books.google.com/books?id=7S7blnVBzosC&pg=PA65&dq=%22resident+advisor+of+students%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CDKjU-j2LvC_sQSZpYH4AQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22resident%20advisor%20of%20students%22&f=false) of 1915, we have:

> and I am glad to be able to report that through the generosity of one of the Trustees, himself an alumnus of the College, provision has been made for a **resident advisor of students,** with office and rooms in Hartley Hall.

If "resident advisor" had been intended as "advisor of residents", then "resident advisor of students" would be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how it's pronounced, like most things in English.
In this case, which syllable has the **stress** is what distinguishes (*disTINGuishes*):

- If "resident advisor" sposta mean 'advisor who resides', it's "*resident adVIsor*"
- If "resident advisor" sposta mean 'advisor for residents', it's "*REsident advisor*"

Pragmatically, the first one is much more likely than the second;
but that's because of the way residence and advising work in the real world.
**Not** because of any grammatical or semantic rule.

Comment: I know, but I asked about how it was used when it first was used. Any evidence as to pronunciation then?

Comment: No evidence as to when it was first used in either or any other meaning. Nobody keeps score, you know; the first use is always eons before the first written evidence.